# Minified JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, bundling-and-minification, vendor

Im wondering about minified/bundled JavaScript files and what is causing the resulting file have specific numbers in it. Im a beginner at understanding minified/bundled js files unfortunately.

I have two separate web projects where one is integrated in the other, including it's JS. The two bundled files (vendor.js) are however not completely the same, even though I want them to be. They differ on some numbers, otherwise the same.

First file, have something like this:

```
function getNodeFromInstance(e){if(void ....
return e._hostNode}var r=n(2),o=n(18),i=n(73)
```

Second file has something like this:

```
function getNodeFromInstance(e){if(void ...
return e._hostNode}var r=n(2),o=n(18),i=n(72)
```

Last row show n(73) in the first and n(72) in the second. Both projects are using react as js framework and built using webpack. What is causing these files to differ? Could it be something with the package.json file which needs to be identical, including package versions of npm packages?

Comment: it might be inlined variable, dunno. It could be that you have `num1=2; num2=18; num3=73` in your expanded file and and later `alpha=number(num1); beta=number(num2); gamma=number(num3)` so the minifier just replaced those with the values. Seems sensible if this is the only place these are referenced (or maybe if they are referenced in only few places).